# How to set Image on rounded shape jLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to create a rounded shape JLabel in which i can set an image . As in Google+ , there is a rounded profile picture frame.i am encountering a problem that the image which i am trying to set in JLabel come over the whole screen but not in the desired rounded JLabel.my code is this.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;  
public class OverJLabel extends JLabel{    
public int intX,intY,w,h;   
  public OverJLabel(int x,int y,int width,int height,Icon image) {
        super(image);
        intX=x;
        intY=y;
        w=width;
        h=height;
  }
@Override  
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
   super.paintComponent(g);
   g.setColor(Color.RED);
   g.drawOval(intX, intY, w, h);
 }// end of the overriden label
}// end of the rounded shape JLabel class
```

Comment: this code works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your implementation of `paintComponent()`, fill the component with the desired background color and confine the graphics context's clip region to a suitably sized `Ellipse2D` before invoking `drawImage()`. For example,

```
private Ellipse2D.Double border = new Ellipse2D.Double();
…
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    border.setFrame(0, 0, width, height);
    g2d.setClip(border);
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, this);
}
```